# Given slope of the line, find inclination

Tags: analytic-geometry, slope

What is the inclination of the line joining $(3, 0)$ and $(2, \sqrt{3}) $

Answer: $\frac{2\pi}{3}$

$m = \tan(\alpha)$

So,

$$m = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2}$$

$$\Rightarrow m = \frac{0 - \sqrt{3}}{ 3 - 2} = -\sqrt{3}$$

$$\Rightarrow -\sqrt{3} = \tan(\alpha)$$

How to get angle from negative slope?

Comment: take arctan and do something with pi. Did you graph the line?

Comment: $\arctan$ works just fine with negative argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real problems here, we take
\begin{align*}
\theta &= \arctan(-\sqrt{3}) \\
       &= -\arctan(\sqrt{3}) & \text{since } \arctan(x)=-\arctan(-x) \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R} \\
       &= -\tfrac{\pi}{3}.
\end{align*}

And, as we can see from the picture below, the angle should be negative:

[image: Triangle]

The answer of $2\pi/3=\pi-|\theta|$ is instead the angle marked $\varphi$; this is the [angle of inclination](http://m.everythingmaths.co.za/grade-11/04-analytical-geometry/04-analytical-geometry-03.cnxmlplus).

Comment: Thanks, i got it... Barely. This is what i dont like about math books. To solve this i needed common sense... which was nowhere in that chapter..

Comment: Have used [this](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/trigonometry/arctan.htm) page for arctan table. Needed for next task.